# Setting up tomcat from Eclipse in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat, lib

Ubuntu users were asked to do this as first step to setup tomcat in their machine:

```
Create a directory in your home directory and copy lib from tomcat: 
    1.mkdir mywebbase 
    2.cp -a /opt/tomcat/lib mywebbase/
```

I'm using Mac and second command is not working in my laptop.

It is showing error:

`cp: /opt/tomcat/lib: No such file or directory`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: macOS is nothing to do with Ubuntu or Linux so you can't use instructions for them with macOS. Searching google for 'tomcat on macos' shows plenty of tutorials on what to do.

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial will help you to install tomcat from Eclipse https://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments Mac OSX is a different platform than Ubuntu.  Even though they are both Unix platforms there are differences (though subtle in most instances) in commands, location of installed software, etc.

To install Tomcat on Mac OS X [here is a good tutorial](https://wolfpaulus.com/mac/tomcat/)

You might find using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) a good tool as it will help you locate and install other software you'll need on your Mac OS X in addition to Tomcat.

Again, Unix is very similar across distributions but you need to understand your variant (Mac OS X) in this regard and adapt when using tutorials from other platforms.  Good luck.